# Mongoose return unique documents with count while using populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that will store multiple copies of the same data

Is there a way in mongoose to return all the unique records based on a certain field, and additionally provide the count field with each object, while using populate to get the full document?

A simple example is something like this:

Lets say the data in my collection looks like this:

```
[
    {
        person: ObjectId("123"),
        data: 'this will be random data',
        _id: ObjectId("xxx")
    },
    {
        person: ObjectId("456"),
        data: 'this will be random data',
        _id: ObjectId("xxx")
    },
    {
        person: ObjectId("123"),
        data: 'this will be random data',
        _id: ObjectId("xxx")
    }
]
```

Since I dont want the data field, because this data is random, and I only want a count of the unique documents, my query looks like this:

```
Model.find().select({'person':1})
```

Now I only have the person field and _id.

Now I want to populate the data, so my query looks like this:

```
Model.find().select({'person':1}).populate('person')
```

Then I get data like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Jim',
        salary: '200'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        salary: '150'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jim',
        salary: '200'
    },
]
```

Now what I finally want to get is something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Jim',
        salary: '200',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        salary: '150',
        count: 1
    },
]
```

All the random fields have been removed, and I only get a single, populated document with a count for each unique type. in this case, the name field is used as the distinct field.

So far I could not yet get this to work while using populate. Is this possible to achieve with mongoose, or will it require some manual computation?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a virtual populate:

Person model:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
  },
  {
    // this is needed to display the virtual in json format, like res.json()
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

personSchema.virtual("count", {
  ref: "Task",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "person",
  count: true,
});
```

Task model:

```
const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  person: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Person" },
  data: String,
});
```

instead of searching by task model, you can search by people model

```
const persons = await personModel.find().select("-_id").populate("count");
```

Person collection:

```
  {
    "_id": "639222fa3f87b88812e95d1d",
    "name": "jonh",
    "__v": 0,
  },
  {
    "_id": "639222fffcd0793b0580302e",
    "name": "joseph",
    "__v": 0,
  }
```

Tasks collection:

```
  {
    "_id": "6392231815cd8663c5671edf",
    "person": "639222fffcd0793b0580302e",
    "data": "some data",
  },
  {
    "_id": "6392231a15cd8663c5671ee1",
    "person": "639222fffcd0793b0580302e",
    "data": "some data",
  },
  {
    "_id": "639223337409d3e1a1f741ac",
    "person": "639222fa3f87b88812e95d1d",
    "data": "some data",
  }
```

and the result of the query:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "639222fa3f87b88812e95d1d",
    "name": "jonh",
    "count": 1,
    "id": "639222fa3f87b88812e95d1d"
  },
  {
    "_id": "639222fffcd0793b0580302e",
    "name": "joseph",
    "count": 2,
    "id": "639222fffcd0793b0580302e"
  }
]
```

"id" field is added for `toJSON: { virtuals: true }`, you can ignore it.

I hope it helps you, here the docs: [enter link description here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)